# Will a 64 bit operating system ran as fast and smooth from a flash drive as the 32 bit version does?

Tags: 64-bit, live-usb, usb-drive, 32-bit

I have a bootable flash drive that i use ubuntu from. The computer i use it on is powerful enough to run a 64 bit operating system(windows is installed). Does the fact that it is 64 bit matter in terms of a bootable flash drive.

Sorry if that doesnt make sense
I know that 64 bit can address more RAM than 32 bit OS's

i guess this isnt specific to ubuntu only, should i ask somewhere else?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

64-bit executables are slightly larger (because of the pointer sizes) but not to a degree that would make a significant difference.

You're likely to see an improvement in application performance from running in 64-bit mode though.

Comment: the 64-bit version will also use slightly more RAM but not that much.

Comment: +1. 64 bit will run about the same as 32 bit, but you'll only want to use it if you have 4GB+ of RAM, otherwise it's [not worth it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#32-bit_vs_64-bit).

Comment: @searchfgold6789, 64 bit apps are also faster, and is now the recommended system to install.